# SEO Url in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an application in .NET Core 3.1 and I should rewrite search engine optimized URLs.

At the moment the urls are the standard ones of the MVC pattern (/Controller/ Action/Id) for example:
/News/Detail/21

```
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute (
     name: "default",
     pattern: "{controller = Home}/{action = Index}/{id?}");
```

The optimal result would be:
/en/news/21/title-news

How can I proceed? I have tried but there seem to me too many techniques from rewrite to middleware and I can't understand which one is right for me.

Do you have any examples to do this in a simple way if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new route for news before the default route:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "news",
        pattern: "{lng}/news/{id}/{titleNews}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "NewsAction" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

The controller action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NewsAction(string lng, int id, string titleNews)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a Good and sample solution!! Thank You!
But if i want no parameter "string titleNews" and "string lng" in NewsAction? because this parameters in logic code of action are not useful.... exist a different solution?

Comment: The routing works this way, mapping route parameters to the method parameters.